# Modifying and splitting row names in an R data frame

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I've got the following table with expression data for some genes:

```
> exp_table
                                                exp
PITG_00005b                              0.16442671
PITG_00005a                              0.94545358
PITG_00004                               0.86324023
PITG_00003                               0.04110668
PITG_00002                               1.10988029
MERGED:PITG_23067_PITG_23068_PITG_16110 34.11854242
MERGED:PITG_23017_PITG_23018             0.00000000
```

What I'm trying to do is to clean this table up, so that gene names are split as with the following code I used for other purposes:

```
> exp_names <- gsub("[a-e]", "", rownames(exp_table))
> exp_names <- gsub("MERGED:", "", exp_names)
> exp_names <- strtrim(unlist(strsplit(exp_names, "(?<=[0-9]_)", perl=TRUE)), 10)
> exp_names
 [1] "PITG_00005" "PITG_00005" "PITG_00004" "PITG_00003" "PITG_00002" "PITG_23067"
 [7] "PITG_23068" "PITG_16110" "PITG_23017" "PITG_23018"
```

i.e., in the data frame I need:
if there is an additional letter at the end of the gene (a or b) it should be removed and all gene 'copies' should be assigned an average expression level (here, both 'copies' of PITG_00005 should be assigned exp = (0.16442671 + 0.94545358)/2),
all the genes that were previously merged should have the same expression level assigned (i.e., 34.11854242 for all of "PITG_23067", "PITG_23068", "PITG_16110").

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: What happens to PITG_00005b and PITG_00005a, what value do they get? 0.16442671 or 0.94545358?

Comment: True, I forgot about that... Just edited my question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# example data
exp_table <- read.table(text = " exp
PITG_00005b                              0.16442671
PITG_00005a                              0.94545358
PITG_00004                               0.86324023
PITG_00003                               0.04110668
PITG_00002                               1.10988029
MERGED:PITG_23067_PITG_23068_PITG_16110 34.11854242
MERGED:PITG_23017_PITG_23018             0.00000000")
```

Extending on your *regex* steps to get IDs, I am creating a look-up *dataframe*:

```
exp_names <- gsub("[a-e]", "", rownames(exp_table))
exp_names <- gsub("MERGED:", "", exp_names)
exp_names <- stack(
  setNames(
    lapply(strsplit(exp_names, "(?<=[0-9]_)", perl = TRUE), strtrim, width = 10),
    rownames(exp_table)))
```

Then *merge* and get *mean* when the is ID is not unique:

```
res <- merge(exp_names, exp_table, by.x = "ind", by.y = 0)
aggregate(exp ~ values, res, mean)
#       values         exp
# 1 PITG_00002  1.10988029
# 2 PITG_00003  0.04110668
# 3 PITG_00004  0.86324023
# 4 PITG_00005  0.55494014
# 5 PITG_16110 34.11854242
# 6 PITG_23017  0.00000000
# 7 PITG_23018  0.00000000
# 8 PITG_23067 34.11854242
# 9 PITG_23068 34.11854242
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the string manipulations in an `lapply`. This gives you a list format that can be exploited with the `length` information to `rep`eat the values.

```
rn <- rownames(exp_table)
rn <- gsub("MERGED:", "", rn, fixed=T)
rn <- unlist(lapply(rn, strsplit, "(?<=[0-9]_)", perl=TRUE), recursive=F)
rn <- lapply(rn, strtrim, 10)
(tmp <- unlist(mapply(function(x, y) 
  setNames(rep(exp_table[x, 1], length(y)), y), 1:nrow(exp_table), rn)))
# PITG_00005  PITG_00005  PITG_00004  PITG_00003  PITG_00002 
# 0.16442671  0.94545358  0.86324023  0.04110668  1.10988029 
#  PITG_23067  PITG_23068  PITG_16110  PITG_23017  PITG_23018 
# 34.11854242 34.11854242 34.11854242  0.00000000  0.00000000
```

The vector can be `aggregate`d using the `mean` to get the final result.

```
a <- aggregate(tmp ~ nm, data.frame(res, nm=names(tmp)), mean)
res <- `rownames<-`(a[, 2, F], a$nm)
res
#                    res
# PITG_00002  1.10988029
# PITG_00003  0.04110668
# PITG_00004  0.86324023
# PITG_00005  0.55494014
# PITG_16110 34.11854242
# PITG_23017  0.00000000
# PITG_23018  0.00000000
# PITG_23067 34.11854242
# PITG_23068 34.11854242
```

---

*Data:*

```
exp_table <- structure(list(exp = c(0.16442671, 0.94545358, 0.86324023, 0.04110668, 
1.10988029, 34.11854242, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("PITG_00005b", 
"PITG_00005a", "PITG_00004", "PITG_00003", "PITG_00002", "MERGED:PITG_23067_PITG_23068_PITG_16110", 
"MERGED:PITG_23017_PITG_23018"))
```